# WindowsError: [Error 32] when I do shutil.move?

Tags: python, windows

I get `WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` in the except block. How can this happen?

```
try:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(folder, name), folder)
except shutil.Error:
    # Handling Error: Destination already exists
    unique_name = "%s_%s" %(name, time.time())
    shutil.move(os.path.join(folder, name), os.path.join(folder, unique_name))
```

Assuming I can handle the exception like this in Windows (I am hoping the first `shutil.move` doesn't lock the file or anything if there is an exception), is it like `shutil.Error` was raised in the try block because the file already existed and it went into the except block where it tried to move it with the new file name only to find that its used by another process?

If I were to write `shutil.move` operations as a Python thread, would there be a possibility of two threads trying to do the same thing? Or that won't happen because there is a GIL lock forcing sequential execution?

In Windows, just generally, can I open two files for writing at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or that won't happen because there is a GIL lock making is happen in sequence?

Even though the threads are happening in sequence, it doesn't mean they are letting go of their file handler, meaning the file is still locked when the thread using it isn't active.

> is it like shutil.Error happened in the try block because the file already existed

If both your `shutil.move` failed, that means the problem is with reading the source file, not writing to a target file. There is another process (or perhaps earlier in your own Python process?) that has opened the file, and hasn't rescinded its read-lock on the file.

Comment: We hardly have an operation other than shutil.move. I will check for any open calls, however if it was the same process, does it make sense to say "process cannot access the file because its used by another process" it should say its locked by the same process isn't it - or is that "another process" generic term for all process including self like it knows a process has a lock but its not going to check if its self because there is no need to ascertain that.

Comment: It's not a lock. Kernel `File` objects that reference the same file have to agree on the sharing mode for read, write, and delete access. If another `File` object has the file open with delete access (also used for move/rename), then opening the file again requires setting the share mode to at least `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`. The same goes for readers and `FILE_SHARE_READ` and writers and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`. The C runtime's `_open` function shares read and write access, but not delete access. You have to use WinAPI `CreateFile` to share delete access.